# How to enable express Vulnerability assessment on Azure SQL Server using AzAPI provider

Tags: terraform, azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure

There is an option to execute Vulnerability Assessment with [an express configuration which doesn't require storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-enable#express-configuration).

I want to use AzAPI update resource to set this, but I don't see this option on [the definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/vulnerabilityassessments?pivots=deployment-language-terraform).

```
resource "azapi_resource" "symbolicname" {
  type = "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments@2022-05-01-preview"
  name = "default"
  parent_id = "string"
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      recurringScans = {
        emails = [
          "string"
        ]
        emailSubscriptionAdmins = bool
        isEnabled = bool
      }
      storageAccountAccessKey = "string"
      storageContainerPath = "string"
      storageContainerSasKey = "string"
    }
  })
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It may be helpful to reference the documentation instead of a Microsoft tutorial: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/latest/docs/resources/azapi_resource

Comment: There is an open issue in [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19971) for enabling vulnerability assessments on sql servers as "express" configuration is not supported with the respective resources in terraform. @Krzysztof Madej

Answer (score 0):

> How to enable express Vulnerability assessment on Azure SQL Server using AzAPI provider:

After a workaround on your requirement, I found there that there is
**"no direct way to automate the express vulnerability assessment on SQL server utilizing bicep"**. You must use Azure `PowerShell` or `CLI` to make it operate beyond the Azure portal.

I tried an alternative way with the `azapi_update_resource` resource to enable vulnerability assessment, however it only works well when the `storagecontainerpath` attribute is added if you'd like to use a bicep.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "1.9.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}

provider "azapi"{}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
name = "xxxx"
}
data "azurerm_mssql_server" "example"{
name = "newser"
resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

data "azurerm_mssql_database" "example" {

name = "newdb"
server_id = data.azurerm_mssql_server.example.id

}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "example" {
  type = "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments@2022-05-01-preview"
  name = "expressjahc"
  parent_id = data.azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      recurringScans = {
        isEnabled = true
      }
     storageContainerPath = "https://<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/new"
    }
  })
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]